# How can I quit an app using Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I want to quit certain applications on my Mac using Terminal. For example, how do I kill “Slack”? Do I need its PID number?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use AppleScript to tell the application to quit:

```
osascript -e 'quit app "Slack"'
```

this will tell the application to quit and will start all the save and cleanup tasks. Or you can send the `TERM` signal with `pkill` but it could be that the application will not shut down cleanly

```
pkill -x Slack
```

Comment: This is the best method, because it replicates what happens when you use `File>Quit` from the menu.

Comment: Huh. I've always used `osascript -e 'tell application "Slack" to quit'` but if the shorter syntax works, then that's obviously preferable. This is definitely a better answer than anything suggesting `kill` or any of its variants.

Comment: @TJLuoma I think if you select the correct signal, then `pkill` is as graceful as any other method.  I too favour the AppleScript, though created a function `quit` to make it breezy.  However, if creating an AppleScript process isn’t necessary, `pkill -QUIT -x Slack` should be fine.

Comment: @CJK No signals are sent to a different procedure in the app than putting something on the message queue. If the app is well written then the signal should shut the app down properly but I suspect most apps aren't well written

Comment: @mmmmmm You need a comma after _"No"_, because its omission completely inverts your statement, which I only just realised after composing a reply to your comment as written to contest your assertion. Luckily, for some reason, I switched voice when reading it again in my head, and now I completely agree with what you said. But I'm not sure how it follows on from my comment 2 years ago (although I realise now that the default `SIGTERM` signal is supposed to terminate apps gracefully and permit clean-up tasks to be completed).

Comment: Yes it should have had a comma. The issue is pkill is not as graceful as the osascript in practice. Apps should deal with SIGTERM but it is not the main message loop and many don't. Also the osascript method allows the app to ask the user if they are sure - wether that is good or bad depends.

Comment: I've tried both methods and only `osascript` works (AltTab in this case). If someone wants to add this in zsh, for example, you can try `alias quit_alt_tab='osascript -e "quit app \"AltTab\""'`

Answer (score 57):

No, you do not need to know its **PID**.

You can use:

```
pkill -x Slack
```

Or:

```
killall Slack
```

---

**Note:** Be sure to read the *manual page* for whichever *command* you choose to use, in order to see the various *options* available to the *command*, as may be relevant to its particular usage. In **Terminal** *type* e.g. `man pkill` and *press* <kbd>enter</kbd>, or just *type* the *command* and *right-click* on it, then *select*: **Open man Page**

Answer (score 17):

Since I don't yet have the reputation to comment, I'm saying this as a separate answer. `pkill` without any flags does *not* match a specific process! For example, running `pkill foo` would target processes named `foo`, but would also target processes named `foobar`. This is because it uses regular expressions.

If you wish to kill a specific process, you can pass it the `-x` flag. For example, `pkill -x foo`. This will use exact names instead of regular expressions.

For example, in your case, `pkill -x Slack` will do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

You can install `htop` (via `brew` for instance).

You'll need to run this as root or with `sudo`. Essentially, it's a text
based Activity Monitor.

Select the process you want to kill (either with arrow keys or a mouse).

Then press `k` to send the process a signal and then `9` to choose the `SIGKILL` signal.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure for Slack, but some Applications will run multiple Processes and you may want to kill just one (I find I often need to do this with iTunes, for example). In that case, you can run

```
ps -e | grep -i slack
```

To find all Processes with case-insensitive "slack" in the name. The output should look like (without the header):

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
649 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
```

That first column will be your PID. You can then use that to kill specifically that process:

```
kill -9 649
```

Replacing 649 with your PID you found from calling `ps`.

Comment: kill sends a signal to terminate the app. It is not necessary to use -9 (kill) if the application is responding. You risk to loose unsaved data

Comment: Similarly, if you did happen to want to kill, say,  all 5 instances of some named process, you could filter the output of `ps` on the CMD value and then kill all the first entries on those lines.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft, you can simply use `killall procname`, e.g. `killall Slack` and it will _kill_ all occurrences of _Slack_ or whatever `procname` is. No need to use `ps`!

Comment: So, `pgrep` is a nice command that combines `ps` and `grip`.

Answer (score 4):

I added this to my .zshrc to quit an app using Matteo's answer

```
qapp() {
    osascript -e "quit app \"$1\""
}
```

Usage: `$ qapp Slack`

Answer (score 2):

If the application has a log name, make sure to give the full name which is listed in applications

e.g. close and then reopen

```
osascript -e 'quit app "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.app"'
open /Applications/Cisco/Cisco\ AnyConnect\ Secure\ Mobility\ Client.app/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to kill Slack automatically at 6pm. Just add the following to your crontab

`$ crontab -e`

```
0 18 * * * pkill -x Slack
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use pkill to terminate a running application. For example -

```
pkill Notes
```

If this fails, there is an alternate way

Get the process ID of the app using pgrep. For example -

```
pgrep Notes
```

Then to quit the app use

```
kill <process ID>
```

Comment: If `pkill` fails, then why would `kill` work, given that they do the same thing, i.e. send termination signals to a process ?